# Namespaced controller redirect urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces

i have probably a simple question. I have created a namespace `panel` with `categories` controller.

After creating or editing a category, rails redirects me to `website.com/categories/:id` instead of `website.com/panel/categories/:id`.

I've noticed that in the _form view, the `@panel_categories` argument of `form_for()` function points to `/categories` nor `/panel/categories` and that's causing this behaviour. Offcourse i can add a `:url => '/panel/categories'` param but i feel that it's not the best solution...

Can you provide me any better solution?

Thanks in advance

**Files:**

`routes.rb:`

```
Photowall::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :photos

  resources :categories

  resources :fields

  resources :users, :user_sessions
  match 'login'  => 'user_sessions#new',     :as => :login
  match 'logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout

  namespace :panel do
    root :to => "photos#index"
    resources :users, :photos, :categories, :fields
  end

  namespace :admin do
    root :to => "users#index"
    resources :users, :photos, :categories, :fields
  end
end
```

`categories_controller.rb:`

http://pastebin.com/rWJykCCF

`model` is the default one

`form:`

http://pastebin.com/HGmkZZHM

Comment: could you post your routes.rb file, thanks

Comment: i've edited the original post, please have a look

Answer (score 2):

```
form_for [:panel, @panel_category]
```

Comment: `undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class`

Comment: hmm i don't think so...the fact is i'm not yet familiar with ROR and i'm probably making a lot of stupid errors

Comment: actually this solution works! There's just one mistake, `@panel_categories` should be singular (`@panel_category`) so i'll edit your post. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: uhh, nope, it's not working. After sending a form, i'm getting `No route matches "/panel/photos/1/edit"` error.

Comment: after editing the _form file and adding the code you've send me, the form inside it points to /panel/photos/new or /panel/photos/x/edit depends on the current action. Here is the controller code: http://pastebin.com/weQdBtt6 (it's photos controller but other's looks the same and the problem also appears)

Comment: Weird, it should point either to `[POST] /panel/photos` or `[PUT] /panel/photos/x`. You view code please

Comment: There it is (`app/views/panel/photos/_form.html.erb`): http://pastebin.com/SbaY9Dij

Comment: okk...looks interesting but it's still not there. For now the form is send properly, however it's not saving any field, they are saved as empty

Comment: Check the names of the elements in the resulting form. They are probably of a form photo[attr] as opposed to panel_photo[attr]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the url to a route such as:

```
:url => panel_categories_path
```

I'm not sure what your route is, but this should work with your application.

Comment: yeah i know about it but there need to be a better solution! adding this to each controller and form will be a pain